# Redirect working from www.example.com to https://example.com but not from https://www.example.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I've hosted a static website on AWS using S3, CloudFront and Route53.

I issued a certificate (covering *.example.com **and** example.com) with Certificate Manager and everything is working fine when I enter example.com and www.example.com. Both URLs redirect to https://example.com, which is exactly what I want.

But if i try to go to [http**s://www**.example.com](https://www.example.com) it does not work, although [htt**p://www**.example.com](https://www.example.com) does work. Why is that?

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong in Route53 or CloudFront.

Comment: When you say it does not work - what happens instead? What error/message do you get?

Comment: @MattHealy on chrome I get "This page isn’t working - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have created the certificate in `us-east-1` region to be used with Cloudfront.
2. Make sure you have entered both `www.example.com` and `example.com` in CloudFront Alternate CNAME entries.
3. Make sure the behavior is set to `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`
4. Make sure `index.html` file is present in the origin. It can also be specified explicitly in Cloudfront distribution.

If you can provide your distribution settings, it would be helpful.